# NSWindow endSheet not dismissing sheet while presenting window is hidden

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

As the title notes, endSheet doesn't dismiss the presented window when the presenting window is hidden.

I've created a small project displaying the issue here: https://github.com/R4N/TestingSheetDismissal

- If you click the "Show sheet" button the sheet is properly displayed and then ended in 3 seconds.
- If you click the "Show sheet" button and then go to File > "Hide TestingSheetDismissal", wait 3 seconds then bring the window back up, the sheet is not ended.

I've looked at the documentation for the endSheet method, the sheet programming guide, and searched here, but couldn't find anything that stated a sheet couldn't be ended while the presenting window was hidden.

Does anyone know if this is the case?  i.e. I have to show the presneting window prior to ending the sheet?

**Edit:**

In my scenario the presented sheet shows the progress of a longer running task, so dismissing the sheet prior to hiding the window isn't an option.  My current solution is to display the presenting window prior to dismissing the sheet, but I'd really like to dismiss the sheet while the window is still hidden if possible.  If it isn't possible, could someone link to documentation that specifies that?

Comment: End the sheet before hiding the window.

Comment: @Willeke Thanks for the comment.  Unfortunately this isn't an option in my scenario.  I've edited the question to include additional information.

Comment: Call `orderOut:` in the completion handler to hide the sheet. [Working With Sheets](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Sheets/Concepts/AboutSheets.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001043-57776)

Comment: @Willeke Thanks.  Placing the `orderOut:` call in the completion handler of `beginSheet:completionHandler:` worked.